# What string search algorithm does strstr use?

Tags: c++, strstr

I was reading through the [String searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) wikipedia article, and it made me wonder what algorithm [strstr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz.aspx) uses in Visual Studio? Should I try and use another implementation, or is `strstr` fairly fast?

Thanks!

Comment: fairly fast **for what?** Modern stdlib implementations often contain heavily-optimized, parallelizable functions backed by compiler intrinsics. "Should I try and use another implementation" – As long as you haven't mesured explicitly that `strstr()` is the bottleneck, why would you bother?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Before I started spending a lot of time measuring, I wanted to make sure that `strstr()` isn't known to be a naive approach that looks at all possibilities. Assuming that it is highly optimized, my time is better off trying to speed up other parts of the code.

Comment: I believe, sources for C runtime are available. You can go there and check yourself.

Comment: On a side note, if intended use for `strstr()` is any sort of parsing, Boost.Spirit would be the better approach.

Comment: @SergeyA Good point. Thanks.

Comment: @JosiahDaniels "Before I started spending a lot of time measuring" – nononono, that's the other way around. **First** you measure, and only then you try to optimize.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant ... or first you measure then you decide that it's not worth optimizing.  Too many people forget that some code does not need to be "optimized" it needs to be correct, maintainable, etc.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Perhaps I wasn't clear. I know that strstr is taking a lot of time, I wanted to know if there were theoretically faster options. If so, I would implement a faster algorithm, then measure again to make sure it actually made an improvement. I don't want to get bogged down trying to speed something up that can't be sped up.

Comment: The `strstr` function may be optimized on some platforms to use specialized processor instructions.  For example, some Intel processors have an instruction that searches memory.  These instructions may be faster than using another algorithm.  The majority of the "depends" is in the size of the data.  With modern computers, there must be HUGE data sizes in order for a linear search to be slow.  Remember that every branch may impose a reloading of the instruction cache which would be slower than using a specialized processor instruction.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation in visual studio strstr is not know to me, and I am uncertain if it is to anyone. However I found these interesting [sources](http://volnitsky.com/project/str_search/) and an [example](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/libsa/strstr.c) implementation. The latter shows that the algorithm runs in worst case quadratic time wrt the size of the searched string. Aggregate should be less than that. The algorithmic limit of non stochastic solutions should be that.

What is actually the case is that depending the size of the input it might be possible that different algorithms are used, mainly optimized to the metal. However, one cannot really bet on that. In case that you are doing DNA sequencing strstr and family are very important and most probably you will have to write your own customized version. Usually, standard implementations are optimized for the general case, but on the other hand those working on compilers know their shit n staff. At any rate you should not bet your own skills against the pros.

But really all this discussion about time to develop is hurting the effort to write good software. Be certain that the benefit of rewriting a custom strstr outweigh the effort that is going to be needed to maintain and tune it for your specific case, before you embark on this task.

Comment: That strstr.c is *not* what any user-space program uses on OS X. It's part of libsa, which is used to build the kernel. As far as I know, Clang and GCC both use intrinsics for strstr. Actually (having just checked), Clang will replace a call to strstr with the load of a constant, if both strings are known at compile time.

Comment: @MarkBessey I was just wondering, how many use cases are there that strstr is used at compile time ( i.e. both strings are known at development time)? Nonetheless, intereseting optimization

Answer (score 0):

As others have recommended:  Profile.  Perform *valid* performance tests.

Without the profile data, you could be optimizing a part of the code that runs 20% of the time, a waste of ROI.

Development costs are the prime concern with modern computers, not execution time.  The best use of time is to develop the program to operate correctly with few errors before entering System Test.  This is where the focus should be.  Also due to this reasoning, most people don't care how Visual Studio implements `strstr` as long as the function works correctly.

Be aware that there is line or point where a linear search outperforms other searches.  This line depends on the size of the data or the search criteria.  For example, linear search using a processor with branch prediction and a large instruction cache may outperform other techniques for small and medium data sizes.  A more complicated algorithm may have more branches that cause reloading of the instruction cache or data cache (wasting execution time).

Another method for optimizing your program is to make the data organization easier for searching.  For example, making the string small enough to fit into a cache line.  This also depends on the quantity of searching.  For a large amount of searches, optimizing the data structure may gain some performance.

In summary, optimize if and only if the program is not working correctly, the User is complaining about speed, it is missing timing constraints or it doesn't fit in the allocated memory.  Next step is then to profile and optimize the areas where most of the time is spent.  Any other optimization is futile.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard refers to the C standard for the description of what strstr does.  The C standard doesn't seem to put any restrictions on the complexity, so pretty much any algorithm the finds the first instance of the substring would be compliant.

Thus different implementations may choose different algorithms.  You'd have to look at your particular implementation to determine which it uses.

The simple, brute-force approach is likely O(m×n) where *m* and *n* are the lengths of the strings.  If you need better than that, you can try other libraries, like Boost, or implement one of the sub-linear searches yourself.